# How to unwrap 80 character text

Tags: linux, unix, script

Many text filess around Internet are word split before line reaches 80th character. I understand it is desirable  by those using 80 character terminals. However  I like sending longer articles to my kindle, but those files look very bad on it. See this picture:[image: This is LWN old issue that is automatically fetched and assembled into .mobi]

80-charater splits are clearly visible when text ends in middle of line.

My question is:
How to unwrap/uncut those lines? "By hand" method is, of course, out of discussion. EDIT: Lets clarify: I'm asking for script or other method that would be possible to run from Linux terminal. bash/ruby/python/perl/awk are ok.

Also, assume I have just plaintext, LWN is just example.

Comment: part of the question is, how is the wrapping done in the first place, and how can you distinguish it from natural line breaks? the text you are receiving must have been modified on the source side, since it can't be re-flowed by your client. if you can answer that question, its a trivial matter to write a shell script to remove the wrapped line breaks. if you can't distinguish between the two, the job gets much harder though.

Comment: Most of the text I'd like to reflow have two `\n\`'s when natural break is (and it happens only when new paragraph is created, so there happends to be second newline created). 
So one `null` would make no new line, two `null`'s - two new lines

Comment: what editor are you using? Can it "Show CR LF"??? I think NotePad++ can.... most decent text editors can, and then you can do a find/replace on the chars.

Comment: @Logman you can also use the TextFX plugin (used to come with Notepad++, I think you have to DL it now from the Plugin Manager) to wrap/unwrap text of an arbitrary width (it will detect and handle the whitespace automagically).

Comment: CR? At the end of line there are only LF's... 
Just like [there](http://www.ict.griffith.edu.au/anthony/info/crypto/encfs.hints)
I also use vim/sublimetext/kate (depending on mood)

Comment: OK, I've booted windows to try this textfx, yes, it actually does the job. However, how do I batch run it on multiple files?

Comment: "Windows uses two characters the CR LF sequence; Unix only uses LF and MacIntosh CR"... http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1552749/difference-between-cr-lf-lf-and-cr-line-break-types  WHen someone reads it and then saves between windows/linux systems its gets messed up.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The answer using `fmt` seems to be to **wrap** text rather than **unwrap** it.

In general, this can be a difficult problem. For example, distinguishing between adjacent lines of text which are deliberately finished early (e.g. bullet points) and adjacent lines of free flowing text can require some context. Distinguishing between hyphenated words split across lines and split up words is also hard.

A common form for prose, however, is adjacent wrapped lines of text forming a paragraph separated by a single empty newline.

This can be unwrapped using the following, rather involved, `sed` one-liner:

```
sed -n '/.+/ H;  /^$/ { x; s/\n/ /g; s/$/\n/ ; p}'
```

Alternatively you might prefer a tiny Python script, particularly if you are going to handle some special cases:

```python
#!/usr/bin/python3

import sys
paragraph = []

for line in sys.stdin:
    line = line.strip()
    if line:
        paragraph.append(line)
    else:
        print(' '.join(paragraph).replace('  ', ' '))
        paragraph = []
if paragraph:
    print(' '.join(paragraph).replace('  ', ' '))
```

If you find yourself adding special casing then you like to find the origin of your line-wrapped text and obtain it in a non line-wrapped form.

Comment: Is there a BSD sed equivalent?

Comment: Also, the python command should probably have a `print ' '.join(paragraph).replace('  ', ' ')` after the for loop if `paragraph` isn't empty to flush out the last paragraph.

Comment: Yep, mostly likely. I didn't actually run this code. I just thought it behoved me to provide a non-sed solution.

Comment: Answer edited for include Alec Jacobson's suggestions.

Comment: `sed` command didn't unwrap for me.

Comment: Now the `sed` command does not show for me, because the source misses a newline after the triple backtick (I swear I saw it yesterday). But I'm not allowed to submit a one-character edit, so dear @AttRigh, please consider making that change.

Comment: how do you apply the sed operation to a file?

Answer (score 3):

I had the same problem -- emailing plain text files (downloaded from a web site) which contained hard line feeds within the body of a paragraph at 80 characters ... and those files look terrible on devices that are (a) doing their own line wrap, and (b) wrapping at a width less than 80 ... that is, the 80-character splits are clearly visible where the text ends in the middle of line.

How to un-wrap those lines?

Use the unix command line tool 'fmt', as suggested by Raúl Salinas-Monteagudo -- and change the line length (-w ##) to a useful number ... for example, 1111 or larger.

Example:

This file from the weather office (forecast.weather.gov/product.php?site=NWS&issuedby=AT&product=TWO&format=txt&version=1&glossary=0) contains single line feeds embedded within the body of each paragraph.

I want line feeds only at end of paragraph.

Piping the output to 'fmt -w 1111' solves the problem (for paragraphs less than 1111 characters in length):

/usr/local/bin/**w3m -dump** 'https://forecast.weather.gov/product.php?site=NWS&issuedby=AT&product=TWO&format=txt&version=1&glossary=0' | sed -n '/TWOAT/,/Forecaster/p' **| fmt -w 1111**

[in code frame:]

```
/usr/local/bin/w3m -dump 'https://forecast.weather.gov/product.php?site=NWS&issuedby=AT&product=TWO&format=txt&version=1&glossary=0' | sed -n '/TWOAT/,/Forecaster/p' | fmt -w 1111
```

.

The pipe to "fmt -w 1111" changes the appearance from this (which appears terribly ragged on a tiny phone screen):

```
The National Hurricane Center is issuing advisories on
Tropical Storm Beryl, located a couple of hundred miles
east of the Lesser Antilles, and on Tropical Storm
Chris, located more than one hundred miles south of the
North Carolina Outer Banks.

Tropical cyclone formation is not expected during the
next 5 days.
```

to this (no line feeds within paragraph -- which then appears nicely wrapped, automatically, on a narrow phone screen):

```
The National Hurricane Center is issuing advisories on Tropical Storm Beryl, located a couple of hundred miles east of the Lesser Antilles, and on Tropical Storm Chris, located more than one hundred miles south of the North Carolina Outer Banks.

Tropical cyclone formation is not expected during the next 5 days.
```

Comment: fmt works for me for wrapping, but not unwrapping

Comment: fmt will 'un-wrap' if the line length is set to a huge number ... some number larger than the largest paragraph likely to be encountered ... a number like 1111.  (By un-wrap, we mean to remove un-wanted line breaks.)

Comment: are you sure? I'll test that now

Comment: woah you're right! nice one

Answer (score 2):

Special cases, [as Att Righ said](https://superuser.com/a/1135986/176100)…

I found this question because I wanted to "unwrap" output from the `fortune` program, which annoyingly isn't even standardized — some fortune cookies are wrapped at 78 character, others at 77, 76, or even 75.
My script tries to determine if a newline has been inserted on purpose or because of the length limit by determining if the line would violate the length limit if it hadn't been broken at this exact length (i.e. if it would be too long if it also included the first word from the next line). As a useful side effect, if the next line starts with whitespace, the first word (as separated by whitespace) is the empty string, so indented paragraphs are never merged onto the line above them.

```
#!/usr/bin/python3

import sys
import fileinput

lines = list(fileinput.input())
lines = [l.strip('\r\n') for l in lines]

for i, l in enumerate(lines):
    # We need to account for 8-char-wide tabulators when calculating our line
    # length, but still want to print the original \t characters verbatim
    sanitized_line = l.replace('\t', ' '*8)

    # Is there a next line?
    if i+1 < len(lines):
        sanitized_next_line = lines[i+1].replace('\t', ' '*8)
    else:
        sanitized_next_line = ''

    next_line_first_word = sanitized_next_line.split(' ', 1)[0]

    if next_line_first_word != '':
        extended_line = sanitized_line + ' ' + next_line_first_word
    else:
        extended_line = sanitized_line

    if len(sanitized_line) <= 78 and len(extended_line) > 74:
        # This line was wrapped due to 78-char limit => unwrap it!
        sys.stdout.write(l + ' ')
    else:
        sys.stdout.write(l + '\n')
```

Answer (score 1):

I just came across this post while looking for way to do this with sed.  Here's my shell script I have been using for most of my unwrapping:

```
# unwrap text with linebreaks in paragraphs and blank lines between paragraphs
# This script reads stdin and writes stdout
# cat is used to read stdin into a here-string so that lnum may be printed at the end, outside of the loop

oline=""
lnum=0

while read aline
do
    lnum=$((++lnum))
    # check for probable blank line by its length, end of paragraph
    if [ ${#aline} -lt 3 ]
        then
        # output concatenated line
        echo "$oline"
        # output blank line
        echo ""
        # prepare for the next paragraph
        oline=""
    else
        # otherwise add it to the unwrapped line
        oline=$(echo $oline|tr -d '\n'|tr -d '\r')
        oline="$oline $aline"
    fi
done <<< "$(cat)"

echo "$lnum"
exit 0
```

Answer (score 0):

## Use `perl -00` to slurp in paragraph mode

This makes a basic unwrapping command very easy:

```
perl -00 -lpe 's/\n/ /g'
```

Adding compression of multiple spaces:

```
perl -00 -lpe 's/\n/ /g, s/ +/ /g'
```

Answer (score 0):

If your input text is compatible with some common format like markdown, consider using [Pandoc](https://pandoc.org/). It's a heavyweight solution if you don't already have the package, but it may fit the bill for some.

```
cat input | pandoc -f commonmark -t plain --wrap=none
```

See its manpage for the full list of input formats, which is extensive. There are several flavours just of markdown, for example. You could also experiment with using markdown or other formats as the output format.

Answer (score -2):

I think that exactly what you want is performed by a simple:

```
fmt -w 80 < input > output
```

Comment: This seems to be the opposite of what was asked.